# How to set onclick of recycler view adapter of other recycler view adapter in a same fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragmentactivity, android-recyclerview

There is two recycler view in a fragment. I'm setting both the adapters in the fragment.I want, onclick of 1st recycler view (onBindViewHolder method),the 2nd recycler view should display.How to set the adapter of 2nd recycler view, please help me...

Answer (score 0):

May your own callback then implement in fragment, send callback from Your first recyclerview to fragment then do what every you want in callback method then call datasetnotifychange of your second recyclerview then you will see the changes in second recyclerview as soon as you click in first. In my logic you need to make fragment center point for both recyclerview. Thanks

Comment: You can use Android studio and create a project with list Fragment, you will get and idea, about set callback..4